# Probelm with Server-Client Application using Usb with Adb (Android & Node.js)

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, adb

I'm trying to send Coordinates from my phone to my computer using usb.
I'm using Socket.io to connect a Node.js server with an android Client and I'm using 
`adb reverse tcp:9002 tcp:9002` to connect the Ports.

This is how the Node.js-Server looks:

```
const express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

res.send('Server is running on port 9002')
});

io.on('connection',(socket) =>{
console.log('Android Connected')

socket.on('join', function() {

    console.log('Android Ready')

    //res.send('Android just connected')

    socket.broadcast.emit('userjoinedthechat', " : Android has joined ")
});

socket.on('message',(messageContent) => {
    console.log(messageContent)

    var numbers = messageContent.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    var x = numbers[0];
    var y = numbers[1];

    console.log("Thats X: " +x+ "and Y: "+y);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Android has left');
})



})

server.listen(9002,()=>{

    console.log('Node app is running on port 9002')

});
```

This is the MainActivity of the Android Client:

```
package com.example.calibrator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;
private IOSender io;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Get Screenheight and Screenwidth of the Display
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    // set the Layout to fit the Screen
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    io = new IOSender();
    io.connect();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){

    RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    //MessageSender messageSender= new MessageSender();
    //JSSender jsSender = new JSSender();


    //Points where the Display is touched
    int points = e.getPointerCount();

    //useless?
    layout.removeAllViews();

    //clean the Layout if the last Finger is up
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        layout.removeAllViews();


    }else{
        //Show Coordinates of the Touch
        for(int i = 0; i < points;i++){

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            int x = (int)e.getX(i);
            int y = (int)e.getY(i);
            textView.setText("("+x+", "+y+")");
            textView.setTextSize(30);


            //to get the dynamic Height and Width of the TextView
            textView.measure(0,0);

            TextView tmp = new TextView(this);
            tmp.setText(textView.getMeasuredHeight()+", "+ textView.getMeasuredWidth()+", "+ screenHeight +", "+screenWidth);
            tmp.setTextSize(20);


            //Too close in right corner
            if ( x >= screenWidth - textView.getMeasuredWidth()&& y >= screenHeight - 2*textView.getMeasuredHeight() ) {
                textView.setX(screenWidth - textView.getMeasuredWidth());
                textView.setY(screenHeight - 2 * textView.getMeasuredHeight());
                // Too close to right
            }else if ( x >= screenWidth - textView.getMeasuredWidth()){
                textView.setX(screenWidth - textView.getMeasuredWidth());
                textView.setY(y);
                // Too close to Bottom
            } else if ( y >= screenHeight - 2*textView.getMeasuredHeight()){
                textView.setX(x);
                textView.setY(screenHeight - 2*textView.getMeasuredHeight());
            } else {
                textView.setX(x);
                textView.setY(y);
            }


            layout.addView(tmp);
            layout.addView(textView);
            if(i==0) {

                //messageSender.execute(textView.getText().toString());
                //jsSender.execute(textView.getText().toString());

                if(io.socket.connected()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Socket Connected!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No connection found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                io.send(textView.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }
    return  true;
}
}
```

And this is my IoSender:

```
package com.example.calibrator;

import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class IOSender {

public Socket socket;

public void connect(){
    try{
        socket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:9002");

        socket.connect();

        socket.emit("join", "Android connected" );

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void send(String msg){
    socket.emit("message",msg);
}
}
```

It worked briefly a few days ago, but now they can't find each other again.
There were no changes done to the code that I'm aware of and I don't now what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Please check if both the devices, node js server and android client are on the same network. Also, in your `connect()` method, instead of using `127.0.0.1`, use the real IP Address of the device running Node Server, and try again.

Comment: @Atish They both use the localhost of the PC, because the 127.0.0.1:9002 of the Phone is connected with the same adress of the PC using adb reverse tcp:9002 tcp:9002. They are connected over USB

Comment: Please check for Firewall or other Anit-Virus softwares blocking this port. Also, check if you can manually connect to your socket server using other code (On PC) directly. This is to verify whether your node server is working perfectly or not. Then try and debug the port of your phone too.

Comment: I tested it locally and the Server runs without a problem, but if I even try to do it with my App with the Emulator by using 10.0.2.2 and my Port (10.0.2.2 is a loopback Adress to the localhost of the PC running the Emulator), it won't connect. So it seems to be an Issue with the App itself.

Comment: This is strange. I am still wondering if there is an issue with the app. However, we can take it a look if you are willing to share the source code somehow.

Comment: https://github.com/Quaspiel/Cali
Thats a link to the full Android Project.
Feel free to look into the Code.

Comment: Just confirmed that the Phone can Ping the Server when it runs, so it has to be something with the Android-Code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that fixed it.
For Android 9 and above you have to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to Manifest or the App just outright blocks the traffic without ever notifying you in any way.
Now it works like it should.